# Compatible collections - SOLR 4 / SOLRCloud

Tags: solr, solr4, solrcloud

I am trying to fiogure out what SOLR means by compatible collection in order to be able to run the following query:

`Query all shards of multiple compatible collections, explicitly specified:`

`http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?collection=collection1_NY,collection1_NJ,collection1_CT`

Does this mean that the schemas.xml must be exactly same between those collections or just partially same (share same fields used to satisfy the query)?

cheers,
/Marcin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,

so I have tested all myself and the schema.xml doesn't need to be exactly the same, it just needs to be partially same as defined by the query scope so i.e. if you ask for the `description:text` all collections/shards need to have description field but other fields can be completely different.